# Get name of current form

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a button on a form.
The button name is `bmod2`, while the form name is `fLayOut1`

When a user clicks the button I would like to save the name of the current form and button name

```
procedure TFLayout1.bMod2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
azone : string;
adept : string;
begin
azone := //forum name here
adept := //button name here
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get name of the current form that the event method belongs to, you can access the [`Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Name) property directly or through the *hidden* `Self` object as it's shown in the commented line of code below.

To get name of the component that has fired a certain event, in this case the [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnClick) event, you can use commonly used `Sender` parameter, which is (usually) the reference to the object, that caused the event to fire. Since the passed `Sender` parameter is of base `TObject` class type, which doesn't have the [`Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Name) property yet, you need to typecast this object to a type, that the [`Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Name) property has. It might be directly a type of the object having the event binded or, if you are not sure with it, or if there might be more component types binded to an event, you can use e.g. the common [`TComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent) ancestor class, which the [`Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Name) property defines (as it's shown in the commented line in the following code):

```
procedure TFLayout1.bMod2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  azone: string;
  adept: string;
begin
  azone := Name;
  // azone := Self.Name;
  adept := TButton(Sender).Name;
  // adept := TComponent(Sender).Name;
  ShowMessage('Form name: ' + azone + sLineBreak +
    'Sender name: ' + adept);
end;
```

Comment: `Sender as TButton` would be preferable here since it would raise a runtime error in case `Sender` was not a `TButton`.

Comment: @David: Sender as TButton will raise a runtime exception as well, but foreseeable one and each time a sender will not be a TButton. The Typecast may pass even if type does not correspond to TButton without RTE. To avoid RTE, the required class should be tested using is operator

Comment: @pf1957 That depends on whether the design admits non-buttons firing this event handler. The code as is doesn't and so as is appropriate. Think of it as an implicit assertion. Runtime exception is desirable in case the sender is not the right class.

Comment: @David: OK, if I read your original comment first time, I thougth you recommend to use as operator to avoid exception, not to make sure the exception will be raised and I was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the name of button's parent , above code do it for you but if you really want the form's name that contain button ( maybe the button is on a GroupBox or Panel or etc.) you can do it like this :

```
var
  ParentClass: TWinControl;
begin
  ParentClass:= Button1.Parent;
  while not (ParentClass is TForm) do
    ParentClass := ParentClass.Parent;
  ShowMessage(Button1.Name);
  ShowMessage(ParentClass.Name);
end;
```

Comment: Why would the *above code* would give the name of the button's parent? It would give the name of whatever object you're running the code of its class. Anyway, you can call `GetParentForm` when you need to get the parent form.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're **NOT** building an composite component, you can **also** use the owner of the TButton.

```
procedure TFLayout1.bMod2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  azone: string;
  adept: string;
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := (Sender as TButton);
  adept := btn.Name;
  // adept := TComponent(Sender).Name;
  // adept := (Sender as TButton).Name;
  azone := btn.Owner.Name;


  ShowMessage('Form name: ' + azone + sLineBreak +
    'Sender name: ' + adept);
end;
```

The IDE always make the form the Owner of all controls, not their immediate container (which it's their Parent).